# Validate logged-in user in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, authentication

I would like to know how I can prompt a user that is already logged-in to confirm their login credentials in order to validate their identity.

I see that there are a few functions in the codex that seem to do this but I am unsure where to start or how to use them.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use something like this:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/si-captcha-for-wordpress/

Comment: Hi Aidan, Thank you for your reply. Although that plugin is interesting it's not quite what I need. The background on this question is that I built a form that captures the respondent's signature. In order to ensure that the user is who he/she claims to be, I need to re-authenticate him/her by prompting for their username and password (despite the fact that they are already logged in)

Answer (score 0):

sometime we need a wordpress functionality to activate and deactivate user. or we need to check user has confirm the mail or not we need such kinds of value before user login for this please check below function in wordpress.

```
function check_user_status($user, $username, $password) {
if (in_array( 'subscriber', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
if (get_user_meta($user->ID, 'confirm_mail', true) == 1) { return $user; }
else{ return new WP_Error('Account Not Active.'); }
}
else{ return $user; }
}
add_filter('authenticate','check_user_status', 30, 3);
```

here we have put condition it will only validate confirm mail for subscriber user.

Comment: Hi Anand, Thank you for your response. This method would require the user to enter their email and then click on the activation link that is sent to them, right? In my case I would need the user to be prompted to re-enter their username and password in order to sign and submit the form.